# Give height to all lines from top

Tags: vspace

I try to make a cover like below.

[image: source]

All lines have a specific height value. When i use commands below, line height ruins everything. Because, all lines have their own heights.

```
\begin{titlepage}
\singlespacing
   \begin{center}

    \vspace*{40mm}
    KARADENİZ TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ\\
    FEN BİLİMLERİ ENSTİTÜSÜ\\
    \vspace*{40mm}
    ABC MÜHENDİSLİĞİ ANABİLİM DALI\\
    \vspace*{30mm}
    TEZ KONUSU\\
    \vspace*{70mm}
    YÜKSEK LİSANS TEZİ\\
    \vspace*{30mm}
    AD SOYAD\\
    \vspace*{40mm}
    Mayıs 2019\\
    TRABZON\\

  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

So, i want to give a value to all lines from top. But how? Thank you.

Comment: I'd use TiKz for that: you can give the position of every nodes from the page dimension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,4cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering KARADENİZ TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ\\ FEN BİLİMLERİ ENSTİTÜSÜ}};
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,8cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering ABC MÜHENDİSLİĞİ ANABİLİM DALI}};
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,11cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering TEZ KONUSU}};
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,18cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering YÜKSEK LİSANS TEZİ}};
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,21cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering AD SOYAD}};
            \node at ($(current page.north)-(0,25cm)$) [anchor=north] {\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Mayıs 2019\\ TRABZON}};

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

a variation of the [NBur's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/151808/nbur) answer (which solve your problem) which exploit `tikz` library `positioning` and has slightly shorter code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{tikz}               % add to your document (only in the case, if you not already use)
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    % add to your document (only in the , if you not already use)

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
            every node/.style = {align=center}
                                ]
            \coordinate (cpn) at (current page.north);
            \node[below= 4cm of cpn] {KARADENİZ TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ\\ FEN BİLİMLERİ ENSTİTÜSÜ};
            \node[below= 8cm of cpn] {ABC MÜHENDİSLİĞİ ANABİLİM DALI};
            \node[below=11cm of cpn] {TEZ KONUSU};
            \node[below=18cm of cpn] {YÜKSEK LİSANS TEZİ};
            \node[below=21cm of cpn] {AD SOYAD};
            \node[below=25cm of cpn] {Mayıs 2019\\ TRABZON};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**note:** to obtain final looks of title page you need to compile document at least two times

Comment: Thank you. \documentclass is defined as \documentclass[12pt]{report} in my main.tex file. I added your code to main.tex file but it doesn't work. I am a very new latex user, can you explain that how can i use this codes?

Comment: solution is independent from used document class and  it had to work, but for final looks you need to compile document at least two times. i edit my answer, which now use your document class and contains comments which should help you.

Comment: Your edited codes are worked perfect. Thank you!